# angular cli create new model for service from array

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

using angular cli I need to generate a model to pass to my service.

(The full model I am attempting to create is shown below.)

The problem I am having is the mergeLines aspect of the model and how I create it...

The data needed for mergeLines is presently held in an object called incomingStepsData which contains 4 properties of dataStepId, endpointName, type and itemName.

For the purposes of the model I only need to access 2 properties in this object: dataStepId and itemName ("name" in the model)

So my query is how can I generate this part of my model by iterating through incomingDataSteps and only pass in the 2 items I need from incomingDataSteps in order to build it?

In my service file I have this class defined:

```
export class MergeData {
  timeoutInSeconds: number; // e.g. 60
  mergeType: number; // 1, 2, 3 or 4
  outgoingDataType: number; // 1 or 2
  mergeLines: any; // an array
  id: number // e.g. 500
}
```

The final model example is shown below

```
"timeoutInSeconds": 60,
    "mergeType": 2,
    "outgoingDataType": 1,
    "mergeLines": [
        {
            "dataStepId": 500,
            "name": "Xml5"
        },
        {
            "dataStepId": 501,
            "name": "Xml4"
        }
    ],
    "id": 500
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How is it that your data is coming from REST?

Comment: Hi, I am generating this model from local data in my application and pushing it through the service to be saved in the db. Next stage of my project is to retrieve the data back and apply it to the app. At this stage I am just trying to compile the data into the format the service is expecting which is shown in the example model at the bottom of my post. I am compiling the top level of the model fine, it is the ability to generate the mergeLines array that is causing me issue. Thanks

Comment: deine merge lines attribute like this  
mergeLines:{dataStepId:number , name:string}=[]